# Dealing with Variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a rudimentary question. And I apologize for it being so agonizingly simple. I am watching a video from AppAcademy dealing with variables. I've pasted the first 3 variables being asked. I understand how the variables works in 1. and 2. But, in the third variable being mentioned, `num % 2 == 0`. The instructor mentions the 42 was his previous number. I got my answer of True based off of the original variable of `num = 40` He's saying its 42. I thought code is read top to bottom? Does the  `num += 2` which is 42, supersede the original variable of 40?  Thanks for your help!

```rb
#example 1
num = 40
num + 5
puts "---1:"
puts num  # 40 - I understand the num + 5 won't make it 45.

# example 2
num += 2
puts "---2:"
puts num  # 42

# example 3
isEven = num % 2 == 0
puts "---3:"
puts isEven  # true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand the confusion. Do you understand the `+=` operator? It takes the previous value, 40, and adds two to it, storing it back in the original variable.

Comment: Hi ggorlen! Thank you for replying! I understand the += operator. It would be like num = num + 2 right? So, does this new variable using += change the original variable of 40? I would not longer refer to num variable as 40 but, instead as 42. Since, the num += 2 changed the variable? I was just confused why in the example, he referred to 42 instead of the original form of the variable.

Comment: Yes, at the end of the second example, `num` has the value 42. So it has that value as the starting point for the third example, as your instructor indicated.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. I understand now!